Issue with Reduction of Complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind
I am attempting to reduce the following equation:
y == 
I’ve entered it to be reduced as such, where L = 3.95:

By what means may this be properly reduced for y?
Both WolframAlpha and Desmos provide implicit plots, indicating the possibility of reduction.


Thank you for all help!

Try to plot the y==… with ContourPlot[y==(*…*),{x,-1,1},{y,1,3}]

It is unlikely that there is a closed form solution to y==…

It is interesting that the plot in the image is still labeled as an Implicit Plot. The ImplicitPlot command was superseded long ago by the ContourPlot.

"Both WolframAlpha and Desmos provide implicit plots, indicating the possibility of reduction." Sadly a reduction isn't necessary for implicit plot. As shown by @CraigCarter , to create an implicit plot, we don't need to know the reduction of the equation, ContourPlot will handle the equation directly (with numeric methods).

With $x^2 y^2 = m$ the two integrals
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{1+m \sin ^2\theta } \ d\theta +\sqrt{m+1} \ \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)\ \sin ^2(\theta )} \ d\theta $$
can be reduced to standard form   to
$$ \text{Assuming}\left[-1<m<1,\quad \text{FullSimplify}\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{1\ + \ m \sin ^2\theta} \ d\theta +\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{m\ + 1 \ -m \ \sin ^2\theta } \ d\theta \right]\right]  \quad \to  \quad 2 \ \text{EllipticE}(-m)$$
